# Unable to append user pick from book list to cart

Tags: python-3.x

"""
    carts = []
    category = 1
    while True:
        print(category_menu)
        category = input()
        if(category not in ["1", "2", "3", "c"]):
            os.system("clear")
            print("### Invalid choice. Pick again ###")
            continue

```
    elif(category == "1"):
        item_pic = itemMenu('Books', bookList)
        user_pick = input("Pick one of the item")
        carts.append(bookList[int(item_pic - 1)])
```

"""

Comment: Please properly format your question and add some explanation of the desired behavior.

Comment: Use backticks not double quotes or add 4 spaces